# Wrong encoding of dynamic block properties problem when loggen in as editor

Tags: rest-api

German umlauts in dynamic block properties ( strings ) are incorrectly encoded/saved in the database, when it's an editor, but correct if edited by an admin.

How to reproduce:

1. Create a dynamich block plugin:
   testblock.php

```
    <?php
    /**
     * Plugin Name: Gutenberg wrong encoding example dynamic
     */
     
    function test_callback( $block_attributes, $content ) {
    
        return '<p>'.$block_attributes['dataTest'].'</p>';
    }
     
    function wrong_encoding_dynamic() {
    
        wp_register_script(
            'test',
                    plugins_url( 'testblock.js',__FILE__ ), 
                    
                    array( 'wp-editor', 'wp-i18n', 'wp-element', 'wp-components', 'wp-blocks' ),
                    '1.0.0',
                    true
        );
     
        register_block_type( 'dev/test', array(
            'editor_script' => 'test',
            'render_callback' => 'test_callback'
        ) );
     
    }
    add_action( 'init', 'wrong_encoding_dynamic' );
```

testblock.js:

```
( function( blocks, element, data ) {
    var el = element.createElement,
        registerBlockType = blocks.registerBlockType;
const {
        TextControl,

    } = wp.components;

 
    registerBlockType( 'dev/test', {
        title: 'Dev: Test',
        icon: 'megaphone',
        category: 'widgets',
        attributes: {
            dataTest:{
                    type:'string',
                    default:'ÄÖÜäöüß'
                },
        },
        edit: function( props ) {
            return el(TextControl,{
                                onChange: ( value ) => {    
                                                        props.setAttributes({dataTest:value});
                                                        },
                                          }
         );
    }
});
 }(
    window.wp.blocks,
    window.wp.element,
    window.wp.data,
 ) );
```

2. Login as (Super)Administrator, Activete the plugin, create a new post, add the block and type in some umlauts. Save or publish the post & take a look at the output
3. Log out. Log in as editor, repeat step 2, compare the output.

Example post content in db:

```
<!-- wp:dev/test {"dataTest":"u00c4u00d6u00dcu00e4u00f6u00fcu00dfu00f6"} /-->
```

but should be:

```
<!-- wp:dev/test {"dataTest":"ÄÖÜäöüßö"} /-->
```

Any idea whats wrong?

Comment: They're the same though? Sure they don't read the same to us humans, but that data is still the same, JSON encode it and see for yourself, it's working as intended. If it didn't then characters such as `"` or `>` in the attribute would break the data.

Comment: hmmm your example is missing the necessary slash escape sequence 

Comment: They're the same for JSON, but have to be the same for humans also saved the same way in db role idependend, right? It's not about `"`or `>`, it's about ä or Ä or Ü. I mean you are a human, not JSON and still can read Ä?

Comment: properly encoded JSON still encodes unicode characters, not just `"` and `>`, remember JSON is intended for machines, likewise with HTML entities and URL encoded parameters such as `%20`. Are you sure that you copied the example correctly? It should have escape character slashes, e.g. `\u00c4\u00d6\u00dc\u00e4\u00f6\u00fc\u00df\u00f6`

Comment: I am sure. It is just copy & paste from db. Try it.

Comment: when you say it's from the DB, how did you retrieve it? Did you copy paste it from the post screen after setting it to view source? Fire up Sequel Pro? PHPMyAdmin?

Comment: This: `<!-- wp:dev/test {"dataTest":"ÄÖÜäöüßö"} /--> ` is also just copy & paste if it's done by an admin, so I expect the same db content if the same input typed in by editors

Comment: It's MySQL Workbench

Comment: and if you ignore the raw output, is this preventing things from working as intended?

Comment: Yes, ''<p>'.$block_attributes['dataTest'].'</p>';' produce "<p>u00c4u00d6u00dcu00e4u00f6u00fcu00dfu00f6</p>" instead of "<p>ÄÖÜäöüßö</p>", but only if edited by an editor.

Comment: My point is same input = same output, right?

Comment: I tried your code, as an admin, as an editor, with 5.5, with latest gutenberg plugin, and could not find a problem. Even then, if it's storing the characters encoded by their unicode values in the database, I do not see what the issue is. Data needs to be encoded to prevent breakage, however even in my tests having checked via the admin interface, PHPMyAdmin, and WP CLI, all 3 gave me back `ÄÖÜäöüßö`, so i couldn't even reproduce the unicode character points. Have you confirmed your database tables were created with the right collation and character set?

Comment: As far as I can tell, the problem is not in the block, are you sure there is no code that filters post content on save? Have you confirmed this example misbehaves in a vanilla standard WP without your theme + plugins?

Comment: Solved it. An old pre-gutenberg plugin seems to be the source of this. I'm not sure what couse it exactly, but realy happy to know it's not wordpress itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solve it:
It's a compatibility issue. In the days before Gutenberg it was possible to do an update of a post bevore saving in this way:

```
// get post object by id
$post_obj = get_post($post_id);         
// do something with post_content
    
// unhook this function so it doesn't loop infinitely
remove_action( 'save_post', array($this, 'replace_postcontent') );
// update the post, which calls save_post again
wp_update_post( array( 'ID' => $post_obj->ID, 'post_content' => $post_obj->post_content ) );
// re-hook this function
add_action( 'save_post', array($this, 'replace_postcontent') );
```

It still works, but cause problems like described above.
The solution is just to use the post object.
Instead of:
`wp_update_post( array( 'ID' => $post_obj->ID, 'post_content' => $post_obj->post_content ) );`
use:
`wp_update_post( $post_obj );`